# Using data which contains ' and ", storing it in WordPress database & displaying it back in a meta box

Tags: php, html, wordpress, escaping, html-entities

I have some custom meta boxes on WordPress, storing some information such as page titles and descriptions, but I am having a bit of a problem which I can't wrap my head around.

The meta input boxes need to be able to accept " and ' (Speech marks and apostrophes), and WordPress is storing the data fine, and I can display it fine on the front end, but when it is echo'd back into the `<input>` box, it messes up because its trying to print something like this:

E.g: `<input value="Hello we're called "example" and we suck" />`

So no matter how I go about it, it's being printed in the page edit screen (once I save) like this:

[image: example image]

or something to a similar effect. Because I need the use of both characters, I can't use either of them to wrap the attributes in as an easy fix.

I'm just having a bit of a brainfart but really can't figure out the logic behind a solution to solve this, because if I escape the characters, they will just get shown to the end user as `Hello we're called &quot;example&quot; and we suck` which will confuse them even more.

Comment: You have to encode them. **Once.**

Comment: Thanks common sense, seems simple. You will hate me for asking this, but what should i encode them with ? I know wp has quite a few sanitizing functions, or should i just straight up use htmlentities or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode with `esc_attr()`, example from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr):

```
echo '<input type="text" name="fname" value="' . esc_attr( $_POST['fname'] ) . '">';
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! I'm an idiot sometimes, but I knew there must be something out there to do it, I was just struggling to find the right words to type into Google to find it